# Defining embeded annotation interface in Java

Tags: java, junit, interface, java-annotations

I have following annotation interface:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface MockToken {

    String user() default "user";

    String[] allowedConfigs() default {};

}
```

Within this annotation, I would like to define another annotation and initalize it in the test. The data should be an array at the end:

```
  "permissions": [
        {
            "resource_id": "xy",
            "resource_scopes": [
                "download"
            ],
            "exp": 1522334692
        }
    ]
```

And I would like to initialize them in the test:

```
@Test
@MockToken(user= "user1", allowedConfigs = {testUser}, permission = examplePermission)
```

My problem is now how to define **permission** annotation and how to define **examplePermission** in the test.

My goal is at the end to have field access like this: mockToken.permissions().resourceId();

Comment: `permission` isn't an annotation, it's an attribute of the `MockToken` annotation. Are you really trying to set it to all of that, I guess, JSON data? You can simply define it as a string  like you did `user` and grab it and parse it. Are you expecting it to get parsed for you from JSON into an object graph?

Comment: thank you. I want to define an object to include in MockToken which includes data like example permissions.

Comment: Defining it as an String is also a good idea. But I tought about defiine it as a class.

Comment: I think what you need is [repeating annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html), at multiple levels, for permissions but also for resource_scopes within a permission, but I have never set up such complicated annotations before.

Comment: My goal is at the end to have field access like this: mockToken.permissions().resourceId();

Comment: Yes I defined it exactly like this, but the problem is how to pass it as parameter in the test:  @Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Permission {

    String resourceId() default "";
    String resourceScopes() default "";
    int exp() default 0;




}

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the types of attribute you can use in an annotation are limited.

Maybe you can directly try to inject the `permission` object itself as a parameter for your test?
In that case, you'll need a ParameterResolver.

In this link they explain this quite well: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions#4-parameter-resolution

You could also consider creating your own junit extension.

You can also try to create a `@ParameterizedTest`?